# Android emulator does not open in windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have created an emulator with target Android 4.4, if I start the emulator get the following exception and does not seen the emulator. Please help me to emulator get works.

```
C:\android-folder\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_19
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 96MB
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Could not initialize emulated framebufferWarning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 512M
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
emulator: WARNING: ./android/metrics/metrics_reporter_toolbar.cpp:164: Can't upload usage metrics: Error
emulator: WARNING: ./android/metrics/metrics_reporter_toolbar.cpp:164: Can't upload usage metrics: Error
emulator: WARNING: ./android/metrics/metrics_reporter.cpp:142: Failed to get a writable, unused path for metrics. Tried: C:\Users\murali.athmarao\.android\avd\metrics\metrics.7408.yogibear
```

System configuration:

```
Windows 7 32 bit.
Ram size is 2GB
Graphics card is Standard VGA Graphics Adapter
```

Comment: Have you ever manage to work with an emulator on your machine?

Comment: No its the first time.

Comment: What kind of emulator? built-in android studio one (AVD)?

Comment: built in Android studio provided.

Comment: Hi there!

You may fix the issue with help of other folks.

I recommended to go for **Genymotion** than Android built in Virtual Devices. It would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

1)Could not initialize emulated framebufferWarning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 512M - you must configure your emulator for less ram size
2)emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it - try to disable it.
3)Try to make your own emulator item

Comment: 1) May I use 512 MB or 1GB
2) how to disable -gpu off
3) Can you please explain little bit detail?

Comment: I think it will be good idea for you to read https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your machine (windows 7 more specifically)  don't allow RAM size bigger then 512 to virtual machine requests `framebufferWarning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 512M`.

To solve this you need to configure your virtual device to ask only for 512M ram.

**TL;DR - How to fix it -** 
1. Go to Tools --> Android --> AVD manager.
2. Click on bottom left 'Create virtual device'.
3. Choose the device you want --> Choose the API (version) level you want (like Marshmallow).
4. `Show advance setting`
5. Inside the tab of `Memory and Storage` set RAM to 500.

Answer (score 0):

My Android studio get works now when disable -gpu off and reduced RAM size.
I have disabled gpu in Android studio version 2.1.2 by `AVD-> Edit or create new virtual device -> Graphics ->software-GLES 2.0`